# EF Core generating basic query which causes SQL Server to timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, entity-framework, entity-framework-core

For what seems like a very basic use case, Entity Framework Core is generating a query which runs indefinitely, eventually timing out.

This is the piece of code causing the problem:

```
if (criteria.Filters.Contains(JobFilteringOptions.OnlyUnpaid))
    query = query.Where(job => !job.IsPaid || job.ChildJobs.Any(childJob => !childJob.IsPaid));
```

What I immediately found bizarre is that the inverse does not cause this problem:

```
if (criteria.Filters.Contains(JobFilteringOptions.OnlyPaid))
    query = query.Where(job => job.IsPaid && job.ChildJobs.All(childJob => childJob.IsPaid));
```

I thought I'd be super smart and slightly tweak the code so that it was more like the second example, but this fails too!:

```
if (criteria.Filters.Contains(JobFilteringOptions.OnlyUnpaid))
    query = query.Where(job => !job.IsPaid || !job.ChildJobs.All(childJob => childJob.IsPaid));
```

I've spent a lot of time debugging this, eventually tracking the issue down to SQL Server itself.

While debugging I also tried updating my SQL Server to the latest version, but to no avail.

I took a look at the SQL query which is being generated, sliced it up, and then boiled it down to the most simple example:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Jobs] AS [ParentJob]
WHERE
    [ParentJob].[ParentJobId] IS NULL
AND
    ([ParentJob].[IsPaid] <> 1 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Jobs] AS [ChildJob] WHERE [ChildJob].[ParentJobId] = [ParentJob].[Id] AND [ChildJob].[IsPaid] <> 1))
ORDER BY [ParentJob].[Id]
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 31 ROWS ONLY;
```

Yep. This very simple query runs indefinitely, eventually timing out.

You'll note I've used a very specific row limit of `31`. That's because using any value below `31` such as `30` or `29` resolves the problem, and the query returns almost instantly. Unfortunately for me, I need more than 31 rows.

Changing various parts of the query solves the problem. Here are some slightly modified queries which return a result instantly:

Removing the offset/limit. This works.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Jobs] AS [ParentJob]
WHERE
    [ParentJob].[ParentJobId] IS NULL
AND
    ([ParentJob].[IsPaid] = 0 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Jobs] AS [ChildJob] WHERE [ChildJob].[ParentJobId] = [ParentJob].[Id] AND [ChildJob].[IsPaid] = 0))
ORDER BY [ParentJob].[Id];
```

Changing the `<>` diamond operators to `=` equals operators. This works.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Jobs] AS [ParentJob]
WHERE
    [ParentJob].[ParentJobId] IS NULL
AND
    ([ParentJob].[IsPaid] = 0 OR EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Jobs] AS [ChildJob] WHERE [ChildJob].[ParentJobId] = [ParentJob].[Id] AND [ChildJob].[IsPaid] = 0))
ORDER BY [ParentJob].[Id]
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 31 ROWS ONLY;
```

Removing the `[ParentJob].[IsPaid] <> 1` check on the parent. This works.

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    [Jobs] AS [ParentJob]
WHERE
    [ParentJob].[ParentJobId] IS NULL
AND
    EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM [Jobs] AS [ChildJob] WHERE [ChildJob].[ParentJobId] = [ParentJob].[Id] AND [ChildJob].[IsPaid] <> 1)
ORDER BY [ParentJob].[Id]
OFFSET 0 ROWS
FETCH NEXT 31 ROWS ONLY;
```

I'm sure there's something going on beneath the surface to do with query plans that's above my pay grade. I'm hoping somebody can point me in the right direction.

I need to either figure out a way to make SQL Server not timeout, or make EF Core produce a query which actually works.

I have no clue how to solve this. Please help!

Comment: Is there a row in the `job` table with same values of `id` and `ParentJobId` columns?

Comment: select count(*) from jobs where id = parentjobid
returns 0

Comment: EF Core query is exactly what it should be, so there is nothing you should do here. It has to be something at the db side. Do you have non standard additional indexes? For instance, if you use EF Core to create the db model for you, there would be an index on `ParentJobId`. But you may have created one on `IsPaid`? In both cases, it would be good to replace it/them with single composite index on `(ParentJobId, IsPaid)` as it would serve both normal relationship as well as queries like this.

Comment: You're right, this solved it
jobBuilder.HasIndex(o => new { o.ParentJobId, o.IsPaid });

Given that the IsPaid column is the only column I ever have to query on the child like this, hopefully this is the first and last time I'll come across this.

Just for the record, I already had an index on IsPaid, but it wasn't doing me any good.
jobBuilder.HasIndex(o => o.IsPaid);

I don't see any harm in leaving that index as is, do you?

Comment: Every index has some affect on insert/update/delete operations. Also may lead to inefficient query plans. Your table is hierarchical and PK/FK serving indexes are much important and preferably should be used by the queries. For instance, just removing that index might also solved the original issue. In general it is better to not have unnecessary indexes.

Comment: Removing that original index is one of the first things I tried - no dice :) Point taken though, thanks for your help!